# Updating game gta5

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v

Ok, so I got GTA V for my PS4 today. I put disc in it, and it said update available; so I went ahead and updated it. After it updated it said couldn't continue with application as something was corrupted. And to eject the disc and delete application so I did that. I inserted the disk back in it said update again. But I tried to play it without updating, But instead it was installing. After it had finished it said disc was damaged, etc. Which it wasn't as game was brand new. I tried to update again but I gave up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How much storage space is available on your PS4? And that sucks ;(

Comment: I am not sure I will check how much when it's finished updating yet again. Today it said in downloads to continue updating so I did n it updated file. Then it said installed after that had finished it said error has occurred

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but for pc. You might be able to go back to the store you bought it from, and say that is broken. And If they're generous they might give you a new one. (Make sure you have your receipt though!) If this doesn't work either contact Rockstar Support, Use the "Banana Disk Trick" or buy a new one. (Last one is a last effort, I recommend trying the other ones first, obviously!)

Comment: Also, you might be able to download it from the PS4 store, If it's in the Disk Tray.